# Export footnotes to a new document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need vba code to copy all the footnotes in an MSWord document to a separate document. I want it ordered with the same numbering in the original document.

I have tried the following code, but it displays nothing.

```
    Dim s As String
    Dim ftnt As Word.Footnotes
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim xRange As Range
    Dim countNum As Integer
    Set xDoc = ActiveDocument
    countNum = 0
    
    Do Until countNum = ActiveDocument.Range.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
            Set xRange = ActiveDocument.Footnotes(countNum).Range
            s = s & vbCr & countNum & vbTab & xRange
        countNum = countNum + 1
    Loop
    Set doc = Documents.Add
    doc.Range.Text = s
    
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you had googled it you would have found [this answer](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-msoffice_custom/extract-footnotes-from-word-to-excel/867a60b0-16dd-4494-80ba-d8da8670cacd) on Microsoft Community that will give you all the information you need to extract footnotes.

Comment: Indeed, the question of how to extract footnotes and/or endnotes has been addressed many times. See, for example: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_mac-mso_mac2011/help-for-extracting-footnotesendnotes-without/818a61af-819b-4aa8-9c88-3063c056edfa and https://www.msofficeforums.com/35017-post5.html and http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-31231.html

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my question.

I encountered errors because the page number exceeds the footnote number. So, there was a problem while iterating.

Footnote length is ActiveDocument.Footnotes.Count

```
Sub SelectA11FootnoteTexts()
    Dim s As String
    Dim ftnt As Word.Footnotes
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim xRange As Range
    Dim countNum As Integer
    Set xDoc = ActiveDocument
    footNotesNum = xDoc.Footnotes.Count
    countNum = 1

    Do Until countNum > footNotesNum
          Set xRange = xDoc.Footnotes(countNum).Range
            s = s & vbCr & countNum & vbTab & xRange
        countNum = countNum + 1
    Loop
    Set doc = Documents.Add
    doc.Range.Text = s
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I think you need to Dim xDoc, at least if you are requiring declaration of variables.